# Confusion over `const_DES_cblock input`

Tags: c, openssl

Why is `const_DES_cblock input` can only accept 8 letters at max. For example,

```
const_DES_cblock input = "hehehehe"; // is fine
const_DES_cblock input = "hehehehehehehe"; // is giving warning: warning: initializer-string for array of chars is too long [enabled by default]
```

The first line encrypts and decrypts just fine. But the second one only encrypts and decrypts the first 8 letters. What's the way around it??

Comment: I don't think you are using `const_DES_cblock` the way it is meant to be used. What happens when your input string is a multiple of 8, e.g. 16?

Comment: @AndrewCheong, im testing it based on http://caole.net/diary/des.html

Answer (score 3):

DES is what is known as block cipher, which means that both the clear text and the encrypted text are fixed length data blocks. In the case of DES, this data block size happens to be 64 bits, so `const_DES_cblock` [is defined](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/6f0ac0e2f27d9240516edb9a23b7863e7ad02898/include/openssl/des.h#L29) as `typedef unsigned char const_DES_cblock[8];`. If you wanted to safely encrypt data that is larger than the block size, you would have to implement a [mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation), but this has already been enveloped in OpenSSL's `env.h`.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, what's your issue here. The manpage for [DES_ecb_encrypt](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/DES_ecb_encrypt.html)
clearly states:

> DES_ecb_encrypt() is the basic DES encryption routine that encrypts or
>   decrypts a single 8-byte DES_cblock in electronic code book (ECB)
>   mode.

So, to encrypt more than 8 bytes you have to pad your data to a multiple of 8 and iterate `DES_ecb_encrypt()` accordingly. But you should probably use a high-level interface like [EVP](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/EVP_des_ecb.html) anyway, where you don't have to care about such details.